# Django direct link to file

Tags: python, django

I have an inline form to upload some files. When I do it, I get these urls :

```
localhost/files/my-photo.jpg
localhost/files/my-pdf.pdf
```

However, when I click on these link, an issue say me that the url is not match. I don't know how to configure `urls.py`. Do I need a view ? TY !

Comment: Are those files uploaded to the server or just static?

Comment: Please show your URL conf, as well as your relevant settings file

Comment: Those files are uploaded on the server. 
For now, I have no configuration for **files/** in `urls.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's docs are surprisingly confusing on this topic. Uploaded file's URLs are discussed in "Managing static files" article, not in "File uploads". Uploaded files actually are served as simple static files:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also make sure you use this feature in development environment only. As @Wolkodav said, you should configure your web server to serve uploads in production. Related links:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#media-url

Comment: @DadaArno You are welcome! Please mark the question as solved then :)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  For everyone else, in my template i used {{ document.docfile.url }} in my href where document was the current document in the loop, .docfile was the FileField and .url was the attribute I wanted.  Then you just add the library references and append the item above "+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)" to the end of your url_patterns.  Brilliant!