# django download file using direct link in production

Tags: python, django

Recently I found the way to download a file using a direct link (like this: [Django direct link to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724874/django-direct-link-to-file)). So I used it. Later I tried to deploy my project in the Internet ([here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com)). Naturally I changed the `DEBUG` option to `False` value in the project settings.

Then I found that the files from MEDIA_ROOT can not be downloaded. I read the docs [django.conf.urls.static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urls/#static). Well, now I know the `static` works just in debug mode.

But, is there a way to do the same without debug mode?

---

Update: I generate the href attribute with this code:

```
href_attr = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, os.path.basename(path_to_file))
```

For testing I created page that just contains `<a href='{href_attr}'>Download</a>`. It works if debug mode is True (in myapp/settings.py). But if I switch it to False I see "Page not found".

The question is the way to expand the urlpatterns with patterns of the static files (the way that works if debug mode is False and does not use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urls/#static) to create direct link to file).

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: @jape, not quite. I have updated the question.